# play sound on button touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to create a shouting game. When user press shout  button, should play a sound. i HAVE THE Code. But my problem is: If user touch the button, sound play good, but button chages highlighted image slow if i press button very fast. If i use my code in ViewDidLoad, button image chages good, very fast, but sound play slow, delays.

here is my code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tap" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer *playOn =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    playOn.delegate=self;


    [playOn play];
```

Answer (score 0):

As You Told You need To play A file on button click so here you should use small audio file on button click for

Here Suppose below Method is Called On Button Click.

```
- (void)playAudio{

  if([player isPlaying])
            {

             [self stopAudio];
            }
   } 
    /* Use this code to play an audio file */
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathOfFile ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = 0; //o for play only once that file.
    player.delegate= self;
    isAudioPlaying = YES;
    [player play];
    //player is instance of AvAudioPlayer.
   //here write code for setting aND CHANging the image.
}


- (void)stopAudio
 {
 if (player!= nil) {
    [player stop];
 //do some task for changing the Image i.e setting the default image
 }

 }
```